# Using label encoder on a categorical feature that we want to embed

Tags: tensorflow, keras, many-categories, labeling, embeddings

I have a dataset with feature that have very high cardinality, doing one-hot encoding is not an option because of memory limitations, so I am currently label encoding this feature and then I feed that to a tensorflow embedding layer, then I train my whole network.

Is it okay to use label encoder this way ? (I know that usually we shouldn't use it for features, but I feel like here the labels are only used as lookup for the embedding layer)

How does the embedding layer learn the embedding, I couldn't find anywhere on google a clear explanation on how the computation for creating the embeddings is done.

Comment: What kinds of data and what are you trying to predict?

Comment: categorical data for multiclass classification

Comment: Assume you have pandas dataframe . Convert your category to pandas category type and use Lightgbm which has a great way of handling the categorical column with high cardinality. The only issue you might run into is when you deploy your model you have to remap your category for the deployment. It is similar to labelencoder. But it is more than that and you can go over to lightgbm and read about the handling of categorical features